# How to put evaluations in between trainings in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorboard

According to my understanding of machine learning(though I am very new to it), evaluation of a model needs to be done during the training process. This would avoid overfitting or reduce the possibility of bad predictions.

I tried to modify the abalone example Tensorflow official sites provided to fit my project and I found out that the code only do evaluation ONCE after model training is done.

This is very strange to me because only one evaluation seems to make the "evaluation phase" useless. In other words, what is the use of evaluation if the training is already done? It can't help to build up a better model, can it?

Here is part of my code:

```
 nn = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=model_fn, params=model_params, model_dir='/tmp/nmos_self_define')

  train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
      x={"x": train_features_numpy},
      y=train_labels_numpy,
      batch_size = 1,
      num_epochs= 1,
      shuffle=True)

  # Train
  nn.train(input_fn=train_input_fn)

  test_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
      x={"x": test_features_numpy},
      y=test_labels_numpy,
      batch_size = 1,
      num_epochs= 1,
      shuffle=False)

  ev = nn.evaluate(input_fn=test_input_fn)
  print("Loss: %s" % ev["loss"])
  print("Root Mean Squared Error: %s" % ev["rmse"])
```

And the training results visualized through Tensorboard is:
[image]

As you can see there is only one evaluation happened at the end of training (the blue dot)

Though I am not sure if the loss not reduced is because of the lack of evaluation, I'd like to know how to manipulate the code so that the evaluation process can be executed during training.

Thanks for taking your time reading this question and I'd love to have a discussion about this, both conceptually and code-wise

Answer (score 0):

> Evaluation of a model needs to be done during the training process. This would avoid overfitting or reduce the possibility of bad predictions.

By itself, evaluating while training doesn't do anything, but it allows an operator to track performances of the model on data it has never seen before. Then you can adjust hyper parameters (e.g. learning rate or regularisation factor) accordingly.

> I found out that the code only do evaluation ONCE after model training is done.

The code snippet you provided runs evaluation after only one epoch of training. You should train your model for multiple epochs to achieve better performances.

On a side note, you should create what we call a "validation set", which is a small subset of the training data that the algorithm doesn't train on to do your training evaluations. With your current approach, you might overfit your test set. The test set should only be used very rarely to evaluate the real generalisation capabilities of your model.